# MySQL Create Or Update based on a Table definition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to take a mysql table schema and then run it against other tables and either update or create. So for instance lets say I have table def like so

```
CREATE TABLE `mobileKeys` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `key` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `expiration` datetime NOT NULL,
  `generated` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now on another database I want the exact same schema table. In some cases the table might not exist at all (so I need to add it), in other cases it might have the table but might be missing a key, OR it could have everything but the values might be different (varchar length changed for instance).

I have about ~1000 DBs that need these updates and have data in the DB and maybe the tables already. I am trying to think of a way to do this, any info would be great.

Comment: If you run `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` you'll accomplish table creation. Update is tough if you don't know exactly what to do with the table - I'm not sure how you can use `ALTER TABLE` to add columns if you don't know upfront what columns you need to add. Same applies to updating columns.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need a programming language to assist you with this process, but it may be a way to use this query

```sql
SELECT column_name 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_schema='[your database name]' 
    AND table_name='[your table name]'
    AND column_name NOT IN ('column A', 'column B')
```

With this you can get the missing columns and can create a "customized alter table".

And after fix the table, You can just sync cross databases

```sql
INSERT INTO databaseX.table_A(column1, column2, column3, ...)
  SELECT column1, column2, column3, ... 
  FROM databaseY.table_A
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into querying the `information_schema` to see if tables or columns exist. The information_schema is easily query-able and has all of the information about your db schemas.

You can check if a table exists like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_name = 'your_table'
   AND table_schema = 'your_db';
```

You can get a list of all columns as well as their datatypes from the columns table:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM information_schema.columns
 WHERE table_name = 'your_table'
   AND table_schema = 'your_db'
```

You can even find how much data is in each table in a database using the information_schema:

```
     SELECT CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name)                                          AS table_name,
            CONCAT(ROUND(table_rows / 1000000, 2), 'M')                                    AS rows_readable,
            CONCAT(ROUND(data_length / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G')                    AS total_data,
            CONCAT(ROUND(index_length / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G')                   AS idx,
            CONCAT(ROUND(( data_length + index_length ) / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G') AS total_size,
            ROUND(index_length / data_length, 2)                                           AS idxfrac
       FROM information_schema.tables
      WHERE table_schema = 'your_db'
-- order by data_length desc
-- order by table_rows desc
   ORDER BY data_length + index_length DESC;
```